# Reto de las compras con 4 y 7

Tags: c++

Se tiene una lista de marcas de computadores y su precio. Se necesita determinar si el precio de cada marca tiene el mismo numero de "4"s y "7"s. Si esto ocurre, entonces se devuelve el nombre de la marca. De lo contrario, se devuelve "-1". Si hay dos o mas marcas que cumplen con la misma condicion, se debe seleccionar aquella con el menor precio.

Ejemplo:

```
LENOVO
4747
MAC
48657
```

Ambas cumplen con la condicion, pero se devuelve LENOVO por ser de menor precio.

Entrada: 
Un numero entero n que representa el numero de marcas a evaluar, y n marcas con sus respectivos precios

Intento de solución:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int n,i;
int main(){
  cin>>n;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    int contador1=0;
    int contador2=0;
    string m;
    string a;
    cin>>m;
    cin>>a;
    int b = a.length();
    char _a[b]; 
    strcpy(_a, a.c_str());


    for (int k=0; k<b;k++){
        if (_a[k]=='4'){
            contador1++;
        }
        else if (_a[k]=='7'){
            contador2++;
        }
    }

    if (contador1!=0 && contador2!=0 && contador1==contador2){
        cout<<m<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<-1<<endl;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

El código funciona bien si es solo una marca, pero si es más de una no sé qué hacer para compararlas en caso de que más de una cumpla con la condicion. ¿Cómo le asigno individualidad a cada marca para que use este código y al final compararlas?

Answer (score 1):

Para cada computadora necesitas almacenar 2 valores:

- nombre,
- precio

Pues bien, cuando lees una nueva pareja de valores la comparas con la que actualmente consideras óptima y entonces te quedas con solo una pareja de valores, descartando la otra. Así pues únicamente necesitas almacenar 2 pares de valores.

Por otro lado, yo casi prefiero almacenar el número como un entero. Eso simplifica las comparaciones y tiene un uso más natural, aunque complica ligeramente el proceso de calcular el número de 4s y 7s.

```
#include <limits>

struct Computador
{
  std::string marca;
  int precio;
};

int main()
{
  Computador elegido = { "", std::numeric_limits<int>::max() };
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  while( n-- )
  {
    // Paso 1: leemos un item
    Computador propuesta;
    std::cin >> propuesta.marca >> propuesta.precio;

    // Paso 2: Comprobamos si cumple N(4) == N(7)
    int n4 = 0, n7 = 0;
    int precio = propuesta.precio;
    while( precio != 0 )
    {
      int digito = precio % 10;
      precio /= 10;

      n4 += (digito == 4);
      n7 += (digito == 7);
    }

    if( n4 == n7 )
    {
      // Paso 3: nos quedamos con el precio más bajo
      if( elegido.precio > propuesta.precio )
        elegido = propuesta;
    }
  }

  if( elegido.marca.empty() ) // Si no hay propuesta
    std::cout << -1;
  else
    std::cout << elegido.marca;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya me sirvio el codigo, solo faltaba poner una restriccion si n4 y n7 eran 0. No obstante, tengo dos dudas. 1) Para que sirve { "", std::numeric_limits<int>::max() }? 2) Me fallo un caso, pero no se cual es, que caso habria hecho fallar el codigo?

Comment: @Jsanabria Lo primero que comentas es para inicializar la estructura. El primer parámetro, la cadena, se deja vacía y en el precio ponemos el valor más alto que se puede almacenar en un `int`. Así nos aseguramos que cualquier precio será más bajo

Comment: En cuanto al error que comentas, ni idea. Si el árbitro no te da más detalles tendrás que probar casos extremos. Un posible fallo en este tipo de programas es el timeout. Por defecto `cin` está sincronizado con `stdin` y eso hace que sea bastante lento. Basta con usar `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` para conseguir una lectura realmente rápida